# Inheritance and Object.Create in Javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance, object-create

look at this code :

```
        var Test = {
        options: {
            name: 'foo'
        },
        name: 'foo',
        init: function (name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.options.name = name;
        }
    };

    var dict = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        var obj = Object.create(Test);
        obj.init(i);
        dict[i] = obj;
    }
```

i don't understand why all the properties in dict[X].options.name in the object dict
has the value same value(2) and the propertiesin  dict[X].name has different value
?

Comment: I believe you need to call `Object.create(Test.prototype)`.

Comment: @Tejs: `Test.prototype` is an empty object.

Comment: @Tejs. No, thats how Object.create works. The `.prototype` is a hack for the `new` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a bit confused here.

```
options: {
    name: 'foo'
},
name: 'foo'
```

as you defined them, and then used in your `Object.create()` statement, belong to the prototype and as such are the same for all objects with the same prototype.

The reason you see `name` attribute changed is because you created it on each instance (essentially overriding that defined in the prototype) by calling:

```
this.name = name;
```

Something that doesn't happen for the object property because you never assigned it directly. Instead it takes the last assigned value (which would be 2 in your example).

Had you written:

```
this.options = {};
this.options.name = name;
```

in your `init` function - options.name would be overridden on each instance and be just like you wanted it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something to do with passing values by reference.

The object `Test` contains a reference to another object in property `options`. When a new instance of `Test` is created the new instance get a reference to the existing `options` instance instead of getting a new copy of the object.

A rough image will be something like
[image]

You can check it by adding the following statement at the bottom of your code

```
alert(Test.options== dict[0].options);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) is clear:

> Creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

So `Test` will be the **prototype** of the new object. All instances reference *the same* prototype and as `options` is an object, they also share a reference to this one.

The relation looks like this:

```
+------------+      +---------+       +--------+
| Instance 1 |----->| Test    |       | Object |
+------------+      |         |       |        |
                    | options-|------>| name   | 
                    | name    |       +--------+
                    +---------+
                         ^ 
+------------+           |
| Instance 2 |-----------+
+------------+
```

Now, as `options` is an object, if you assign a new property to it,  like

```
instance1.object.name2 = 'bar';
```

you are actually accessing  `Test.options`. The result will be:

```
+------------+      +---------+       +--------+
| Instance 1 |----->| Test    |       | Object |
+------------+      |         |       |        |
                    | options-|------>| name   | 
                    | name    |       | name2  |
                    +---------+       +--------+
                         ^
+------------+           |
| Instance 2 |-----------+
+------------+
```

But when you assign a *new value* to `name`,  a new property `name` will be created at that instance. So when you do:

```
instance1.name = 'bar';
```

the result will be

```
+------------+      +---------+       +--------+
| Instance 1 |----->| Test    |       | Object |
|            |      |         |       |        |
| name       |      | options-+------>| name   | 
+------------+      | name    |       +--------+
                    +---------+
                         ^
+------------+           |
| Instance 2 |-----------+
+------------+
```

The same would happen if, instead of just accessing or assigning a property of/to `options`, you assigned a new value to it:

```
instance1.options = {name: 'another name'};
```

results in:

```
           +--------+
           | Object |
           |        |
           | name   |
           +--------+
                ^
+------------+  |   +---------+       +--------+
| Instance 1 |--+-->| Test    |       | Object |
|            |  |   |         |       |        |
| options----+--+   | options-|------>| name   | 
+------------+      | name    |       +--------+
                    +---------+
                         ^
+------------+           |
| Instance 2 |-----------+
+------------+
```

Because of how property look up works, `instance1.options` will return the value of the closest (nearest) `options` property in the prototype chain. Once we set `name` or `options` at the instance, it will return those values and not the ones of the prototype (`Test`).

Comment: I think that doesn't answer the question why `name` varies for all instances and `options.name` doesn't. But... may be I am mistaken.
Will provide my answer anyway.